# Use Lag function in SAS find difference and delete if the value is less than 30

Tags: diff, sas, lag

Eg.

```
Subject  Date   
1        2/10/13
1        2/15/13
1        2/27/13
1        3/15/13
1        3/29/13
2        1/11/13
2        1/31/13
2        2/15/13
```

I would need only the subjects with the dates between them more than 30.

required output:

```
Subject  Date   
1        2/10/13
1        3/15/13
2        1/11/13
2        2/15/13
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This sounds like a homework problem...  What have you tried?

Comment: I agree with cm2. You should attempt the problem first instead of using an imperative tone...

Comment: Its not homework problem it tried several methods. I used 
   proc expand data=test44 out=data2 method=none; by subject  ;
       convert date=lastcall / transformout=(lag 1);
      run;
the problem with this one is i get the lag date but i want only the date more than 30 days. if the date is less than 30 I need to delete the record and compare it again which is little tricky

Comment: I tried 

   data  final112 ; set final ;
    BY subject;


    dif = dif(datepart(date)) ;
    if first.subject then do ;
    dif = . ;   end ; run ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very interesting problem. I'll use the retain statement in the DATA step.

Since we are trying to compare dates between different observations, it's a bit more difficult. We can take advantage of the fact that SAS can convert dates to SAS date values (i.e. number of days after Jan 1 1960). Then we can compare these numeric values using conditional statements.

```
data work.test;
    input Subject Date anydtdte15.;
    sasdate = Date;

    retain x;

    if -30 <= sasdate - x <= 30 then delete;

    else x = sasdate;  

    datalines;
    1        2/10/13
    1        2/15/13
    1        2/27/13
    1        3/15/13
    1        3/29/13
    2        1/11/13
    2        1/31/13
    2        2/15/13
    ;
run;

proc print data=test;
    format Date mmddyy8.;
    var Subject Date;
run;
```

OUTPUT as required:

```
                                Obs    Subject        Date

                                 1        1       02/10/13
                                 2        1       03/15/13
                                 3        2       01/11/13
                                 4        2       02/15/13
```

Comment: Wow that was exactly i was looking for .. i have lot of data to work was just testing on sample. Thanks a lot Yick :)

Comment: as you said it was little tricky since when i used proc expand or lag function it was able to look only one step and moreover i was not able to delete the observation simultaneously. thanks once again